# Azure function Process.Start() C# as different user got Access denied error

Tags: azure-functions

I am trying to run an executable in azure function (v2) with Process.Start command by supplying username and password of a user

```
string nwPath = <path/to/bla.exe>
string dirName = Path.GetDirectoryName(nwPath);
var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
            {
                WorkingDirectory = dirName,
                FileName = nwPath,
                UserName = <username>,
                Password = secureString,
                Domain = <domain>,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                Arguments = @"p1 p3",
                Verb = "runas"
            };
Process.Start(processInfo);
```

This function runs locally with passed in username and password. When i deployed this to azure i am getting following error
**Access is Denied**

I have uploaded executable in azure function by clicking on upload button and the executable path is

`C:\home\wwwroot\functionname\bla.exe`

If i run the process with the following command it works on azure

`Proccess.Start(@"path/to/bla.exe")`

I am assuming process running under a user does not have access to the executable.

Can we give permission to the user to access executable in azure functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you cant specify user permission due to the architecture of azure func.

Try to use   `HostingPath` as a `WorkingDirectory` in `ProcessStartInfo`

```
   private static string HostingPath =>
            Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AzureWebJobsScriptRoot") // local_root
            ?? (Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("HOME") == null
                ? Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)
                : $"{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("HOME")}/site/wwwroot");
```

Comment: No luck after adding hosting path. The executable path exists but the process running under specfied user does not have read or write permissions. I Would like to add read permissions to the user.

Comment: @SudhakarReddy what your console app trying to do?
Also, can you try to run w/o passing  UserName and Password ?

Comment: So if i cannot provide permissions to a folder then is there any way i can run an executable in azure? I would like to run the executable under a specific user.

Comment: if yours .exe app trying to write some data  into /site/wwwroot folder it will receive an exception